# Internship in Germany as a non-EU citizen, it is posible to apply for Visa as a graduate in italy?

Tags: visa, germany, internship

I am a non-EU masters student in Italy and I am a graduate from a University in Italy. I recently got an internship offer from a company in Germany. In the list of required documents, I know that I need to have ZAV (Certificate of the International Employment Agency) to apply for visa.

However, I only know that ZAV issue for student who is still enrolled not for graduate. Anyone can give me advices such as what should I do and which documents needed to obtain ZAV?

Comment: may I ask if you solved it ultimately?